# Default Schema allows dbo table selection without using schema prefix

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, permissions, schema

I have created a Login and a database user on my server as follows:

```
USE master
GO
CREATE LOGIN MyLogin WITH PASSWORD=N'Password123!'
GO
USE AdventureWorks2014
GO
CREATE USER MyLogin FOR LOGIN MyLogin
GO
ALTER USER MyLogin WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=HumanResources
GO
GRANT SELECT ON SCHEMA :: Production TO MyLogin
GO
GRANT SELECT ON SCHEMA :: HumanResources TO MyLogin
GO
GRANT SELECT ON SCHEMA :: dbo TO MyLogin
```

When I log in as MyLogin I can now select objects in the HumanResources schema without using the four part name (as HumanResources is the default schema for this user)

```
SELECT * FROM HumanResources.Department
```

can now be run without the schema name:

```
SELECT * FROM Department
```

This is fine. If I then try to select from a table in the Production Schema without using the schema prefix:

```
SELECT * FROM ProductDescription
```

I get an error as expected. This can be remedied by using:

```
SELECT * FROM Production.ProductDescription
```

So based on this, I need to specify the schema name when selecting from any table outside the default schema.

So why when I select from a table in the dbo schema, do I still not need to use the schema prefix?

```
SELECT * FROM DatabaseLog
```

returns results

I am confused. I thought if a schema name does not prefix the table in a SELECT statement, that the default schema is used and selecting from a table in any other schema would require the schema prefix.

Is the dbo schema an exception to this rule?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need the prefix when some object is in your default schema because SQL Server checks for a non-schema-prefixed object in your default schema first. It will then check the `dbo` schema, so you can actually get away with this laziness in two different ways.

From [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/ownership-and-user-schema-separation-in-sql-server):

> When database objects are referenced by using a one-part name, SQL Server first looks in the user's default schema. If the object is not found there, SQL Server looks next in the `dbo` schema. If the object is not in the `dbo` schema, an error is returned.

They say "one-part name" but this also applies when you reference an object with a pattern like:

```
[server].[database]..[name]
```

or

```
[database]..[name]
```

This is nothing but a confirmation that you should just *always specify schema name*. **Always.**

- [Bad habits to kick : avoiding the schema prefix](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix)